# Should I compress my datastream before I SSL-encrypt it, or after?

Tags: ssl, encryption, compression

### Duplicate acknowledgement: see my answer below for further information

I'm building a simple personal application to learn about binary protocol programming, and for added security I'll be encrypting the protocol using SSL. My context is thus "personal project/experience," not "major enterprise-class operation."

I'm curious how SSL responds to compression; would I get better performance encrypting my datastream *then* compressing it (so I'm compressing SSL data); or compressing my data *then* encrypting it (so SSL is encrypting compressed data)?

My underlying protocol is part of a general networking library that will be used to transport event messages and data payloads between hosts, and at this point in the design phase I expect most of the data will be binary, with only low to moderate amounts of ASCII text.

My answer in advance to the possible suggestion of "implement both approaches and see what happens" is that I *could* make the protocol able to use both approaches, and switch between the two to get performance metrics... but it would probably take weeks or months of actual usage to determine *mathematically-superoptimized* settings, because this will be a general-purpose network library in a bigger application... and so I'm asking this question precisely because I don't want to go there and be *that* OCD. :P

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **[Valentin Lorentz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605002/should-i-compress-my-datastream-before-i-ssl-encrypt-it-or-after#comment47355773_29605002)** I found my question was a duplicate that had already been asked twice.

I found this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4399886/3229684) packed the facts in the most easy-to-understand manner:

> There is no added security (as compression is not a security mechanism), but a properly encrypted message shouldn't be easily compressible (i.e. rule of thumb: if you can significantly compress an encrypted message, something is wrong).
>
> Therefore, compress then encrypt.

References:

- [The thread I was linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399812/is-it-better-to-encrypt-a-message-and-then-compress-it-or-the-other-way-around) has a lot of useful and insightful information on it; I also found that...
- [Someone asked exactly this same question](https://superuser.com/questions/257782/compress-and-then-encrypt-or-vice-versa) on Superuser and it sparked quite a bit of debate and discussion, culminating in...
- [This community blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/03/21/compression-and-encryption/) [which] definitively details the ins and outs.